# Index many PDF Files in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, indexing

iam currently in an apprenticeship and working an a project.
The php has to seachr thru many pdf files and find keywords and list the PDF files that have those keywords in them.

Now iam very new to PHP and iam sorry if this question was allready asked, but i cant seem to find anything that really helped me.

I have found a way to take the text from the PDF files and display them using following code:

```
require( "class.filetotext.php" );

 $docObj = new Filetotext( "./test.pdf" );
 $output = $docObj -> convertToText();

 print $output;
```

(using file to text thingy)

If that helps

Any help is welcome :) Thanks you

Comment: First you need to learn how to list the content of a directory in PHP. Then, how to read PDF content as text (which you seem to have achieved). Finally, for each PDF, how to iterate over its content to look for your keywords, and return the PDF file name or whatever is useful for your code if a keyword matched. Note that this community is not here to implement this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code can you check if a string appears in a text. What you could do is loop through all files find the keywords & if the keywords appears in a pdf store it in an array. Hopefully this helps you.

```
 <?php
     $word = "fox";
     $mystring = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

     // Test if string contains the word 
     if(strpos($mystring, $word) !== false){
         echo "Word Found!";
     } else{
         echo "Word Not Found!";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me very much `  require( "class.filetotext.php" );
$files = glob('./*.{pdf}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $pdf) {
 $thepdf = 'something';


 $docObj = new Filetotext( "$pdf" );
 $return = $docObj -> convertToText();

  $word = "keyword";
     if(strpos($return, $word) !== false){
         echo nl2br ("Word was found in $pdf \n");
     } else{
         echo nl2br ("Word Not Found in $pdf \n");
     }


}
`

I got it work with this code :)